# What are valid values for ai_family?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

The following is the code snippet I've written for accepting connections from the client. I wanted to print the remote host name. getnameinfo() fails with the error: ai_family not supported. I tried different options over the internet like specifying AF_UNSPEC. Nothing is working for me. I printed the sa_family field and it is 62752. Is this a valid value? What am I doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
socklen_t sin_size;
struct sockaddr client_addr;
int sockfd = accept(serv_sockfd,&client_addr, &sin_size);
if(sockfd == -1)
   error("Accept failed");

char remote_host[NI_MAXHOST];
cerr <<"sa_family" << client_addr.sa_family<<endl;

int en;
if ((en = getnameinfo(&client_addr, sin_size, remote_host, sizeof(remote_host),NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD))!=0)
cerr << "getnameinfo: " << gai_strerror(en);
else
   printf("host=%s\n", remote_host);
```

Comment: Before calling accept, you must set the `sin_size` variable to the size of the address structure you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working now. I know this may sound silly, How did you figure that out? just looking at the code or does the garbage value 62752 give some hint that I messed up with some structures?

Comment: Just looking at the code, and remembering what `accept` wants. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is earlier.  The third argument to [accept()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) is supposed to be:

> address_len
>
> Points to a socklen_t structure which on input specifies the length of
>   the supplied sockaddr structure, and on output specifies the length of
>   the stored address.

Also, a `struct sockaddr` is too small to hold any actual address.

Try:

```
struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(client_addr);
int sockfd = accept(serv_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
```

...and then the rest of your code as written.

Comment: If the code is using IPv4 only then `sockaddr` is big enough, though `sockaddr_in` should be used instead. If the code needs to support both IPv4 and IPv6, or other address families, then yes, use `sockaddr_storage`.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. Which one should must specify sin_family/ ai_family, server or client? Sorry my networking knowledge is very limited.

Comment: The family is established whenever you call `socket()` to create a new socket on either end.  When calling `connect()`, an IPv4 client can only talk to an IPv4 or an IPv6 dual-stack server, an IPv6 client can only talk to an IPv6 server, etc.  `accept()` tells you the family of the client that connected, `recvfrom()` tells you the family of the peer that sent data, etc.